# Sticky footer with varying content height without page refresh

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I am using the 'CSS Sticky Footer' technique to have a footer which stays on the bottom of the screen if the content is smaller than the height of the browser window, while it goes down below the content if the content height is larger than the height of the browser window.

This works fine for normal content, however I have pages whose content changes without refreshing the page. (Using Javascript to replace the content of a `<div>`, or changing a `<div>` from `display: none` to `display: block`). When I have a situation where the original page is smaller in height than the window (thus the footer is at the bottom) and the new content makes it larger than the window, the content is put 'behind' the footer (rather than moving the footer underneath the new content).

Is there a way to force the browser to 'recalculate the size' of the window and render the page contents with the new page sizes?

```
<html>
<body>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">        
     <div id="header"><!-- some header content here --> </div>     
     <div id="content" class="footer_padding"> <!-- .footer_padding gives room for the sticky footer -->

         <div class="items"><!-- some normal content here which doesn't change, a list of items in my case, which when clicked, some info is displayed below  -->
              <a href="#" onClick="javascript:showInfoPage('longpage');">Show Item Details</a>
         </div>

         <div id="text">
            <div class="iteminfo" id="defaultpage" style="display: block">
                <!-- default content here, height smaller than window height -->
                <p>Hello this is some content.</p> 
            </div> <!-- #defaultpage .iteminfo -->

            <div class="iteminfo" id="longpage" style="display: none">
                <!-- item content here, height larger than window height -->
                <p>This is some long content...</p>
                <p>This is some long content...</p>
                <p>This is some long content...</p> 
            </div> <!-- #defaultpage .iteminfo -->


         </div><!-- #text -->

      <script language="javascript1.5" type="text/javascript">
       function showInfoPage(slug)
       {
         jQuery('.iteminfo').css("display", "none");
         jQuery('#'+slug).css("display", "block");
       }
      </script>

     </div><!-- #content -->
   </div> <!-- #wrapper -->

   <div id="footer">
         <!-- the sticky footer -->
         <p>Hello, I am the footer, I should always be at the bottom</p>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;    
}

body
{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size:15px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align:center;    
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

div#wrapper
{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%; 
}

div#content
{
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: relative;   
}

.footer_padding
{
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}


 #footer
 {
   position: relative;
   margin-top: -40px;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
   background:#FFFFFF;
   clear: both;
 }
```

I have created a JSFiddle that shows this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/7mUDa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript to position your footer. Make two footers and put them in seperate divs.

```
<div id="footer1>
this is my footer.
</div>
<div id="footer2">
this is my footer.
</div>
```

As you can see, the content of the footer in both the divs will be the same, then through javascript use conditional statements to check if the content exceeds the browser window through:

```
$(window).height();
```

If it doesn't exceed the height, use footer1 with absolute position on the bottom of the screen and keep the other footer's visibility:false. If it does, use footer2 with relative position to the content and keep the othe footer's visibility:false.

Comment: Your solution seems way too over complicated for such a small problem. I would have to repeat the footer twice which is not something simple as 'this is my footer'.

Comment: Hmm, I'll try and take another look today.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. I'm used to doing this with only css. but here is a link that may help with what you are trying to do:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566468/how-to-resize-div-on-browser-re-size

Comment: @JFelton Yes I do want a full CSS solution if possible. The Javascript is just switching the visible content `<div>`. If its possible to have it only through CSS its always better.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, simply add more content inside the `div.page-wrap` and watch the footer get pushed down as requested.

### HTML

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

### CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
```

See [this example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/uwJjr).

**Tip:** If your footer is not a fixed height or you want to make it responsive, you will need to calculate (using Javascript) the `.site-footer` `height` and `.page-wrap` `margin-bottom` value based on the natural height of `.site-footer`. You may also want to update this value when the browser window is resized. Or for a non-JS solution, you can always use media queries.